# Word Find Everything Until A Particular Character

Tags: microsoft-word, vba

I'm creating a Word macro to automatically clean up output from a document generation system. I need to come up with a Word Wildcard Expression to select everything from a particular piece of text up until the paragraph break.

Currently I have this expression, It selects "  **Invalid Merge Field:" and onwards. However this also selects the paragraph break which is not what I want.

```
 {2}\*\*Invalid Merge Field:*^13
```

I have tried using the [!] and @ wildcards but it doesn't seem to be working as expected. It only selects the space following, not the rest of the paragraph.

```
 {2}\*\*Invalid Merge Field:[!^13]@
```

What would be the correct expression to select up until the paragraph break. Is this even possible with the word find system?

Comment: Are you sure the code is 13 ('carriage-return')? I think it is 10 ('line-feed') you need to go for.

Comment: @Aganju Carriage return is correct for paragraph breaks in Word.

Comment: I stand corrected... I never used Macros in word, i do the searching in the GUI, and there you can copy a Paragraph symbol and paste it in the box.

Comment: @Aganju Word 2013+ no longer does the special characters in the Find/Replace GUI anyway.

Comment: AFAIK you cannot do this in Word . The problem is that @ does not work with [!] expressions (just when you need it!). The alternative to @ would be {0,}, but 0 is not allowed. Further, even if {1,} would do, it will match a maximum number of characters (255, I think) and will in some cases only match 1 rather than do a 'greedy' match. You will probably need to do the match that includes the paragraph mark, then shrink the Selection.Range by 1 character before proceeding.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`{2}\*\*Invalid Merge Field:*[!^13]`

Answer not displaying the backslashes, but it should read as per your options above with the following changes:

It keeps the wildcard in your first option after Field: but drops off the @ you added after the "not" match in your second option.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the find as it is, and then move the end of the selection or range back by one character so it doesn't include the Chr(13):

`Selection.MoveEnd Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=-1`